# HTTP Auth with Panther

Tags: phpunit, symfony4, symfony-panther

I'm trying to migrate some tests from WebTestCase to PantherTestCase.
For some of them, I need to authenticate with HTTP Auth.

I used to do the following:

```
$this->adminClient = static::createClient(
   [],
   [
       'PHP_AUTH_USER' => 'login',
       'PHP_AUTH_PW'   => 'password',
   ]
);
```

If I use createPantherClient, the login/password options seem to be ignored:

```
$this->adminClient = static::createPantherClient(
    [],
    [
        'PHP_AUTH_USER' => 'login',
        'PHP_AUTH_PW'   => 'password',
    ]
);
```

I've also tried to pass login/password as the first parameter but it doesn't seem to work either.

I've been looking for some doc on that topic but couldn't find anything. How does Panther handle HTTP Auth?

Thanks

Comment: I've the same problem man, do you fixed it ?

Comment: @eronn Nope, I stuck with Symfony default client. I had opened an issue on their repo https://github.com/symfony/panther/issues/237 but it only got one response, which might help you.

Comment: I fixed the problem with authenticate the client directly passing by the login page and submit authentication form. However, an another problem is that when you're running Panther, it is running with dev environment. So, it's a problem...